# Using a CollectionView to group items within a list view

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on an C# application where I want to display call log information that is read into the program. I want the items to be added to the list view in a group. The group should be based on the call type in the array, for example, inbound/outbound/missed.

Below is how I am creating the array (the data is read in from an XML message.

```
public void processCallLogInfo(string xml)
        {
            List<CallLogInformation> callLogInformationList = new List<CallLogInformation>();
            string phoneNumber = null;
            string contactName = null;
            string contactPhoto = null;

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            var callLogInformationRoot = doc.Descendants("CallLogInformation");
            foreach (var callLogInformation in callLogInformationRoot)
            {
                var callLogRoot = callLogInformation.Descendants("CallLog");
                foreach (var log in callLogRoot)
                {
                    var logRoot = log.Descendants("LogInformation");
                    foreach (var info in logRoot)
                    {
                        CallLogInformation callLogInfo = new CallLogInformation();
                        callLogInfo.contactInformation = new ContactInformation();
                        phoneNumber = info.Element("PhoneNumber").Value;

                        if (info.Elements("ContactPhoto").Any())
                        {
                            callLogInfo.contactInformation.photoBase64String = info.Element("ContactPhoto").Value;
                        }
                        if (info.Elements("ContactName").Any())
                        {
                            callLogInfo.contactInformation.contactName = info.Element("ContactName").Value;
                            callLogInfo.contactNameOrPhoneNumber = info.Element("ContactName").Value;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            callLogInfo.contactNameOrPhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
                        }

                        callLogInfo.callType = (CallLogInformation.CallType)Enum.Parse(typeof(CallLogInformation.CallType), info.Element("CallType").Value);
                        callLogInfo.date = long.Parse(info.Element("Date").Value);
                        callLogInfo.callDuration = Int32.Parse(info.Element("Duration").Value);
                        callLogInfo.contactInformation.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;

                        callLogInformationList.Add(callLogInfo);
                        //iCallLogManager.addCallLogItemToGUI(callLogInfo);
                    }
                }
            }
            iCallLogManager.addArrayToGui(callLogInformationList);
        }
```

Below is where I am trying to load the collection and group by the call type, e.g. INBOUND

```
public void addArrayToGui(List<CallLogInformation> callLogInformationList)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate
                {
                    ICollectionView callLogView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(callLogInformationList);
                    callLogView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("callType"));
                    lstCallLogInformation.ItemsSource = callLogView;
                    return null;
                }), null);
        }
```

Below is the WPF for the ListView

```
<ListBox Height="397" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="491,29,0,0" Name="lstCallLogInformation" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="320">
            <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle />
            </ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding contactNameOrPhoneNumber}" /> 
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

The CallLogInformation class is defined as follows

```
public class CallLogInformation
    {
        public enum CallType { INCOMING, OUTGOING, MISSED, UNKNOWN };
        public string contactNameOrPhoneNumber;
        public ContactInformation contactInformation;
        public CallType callType = CallType.UNKNOWN;
        public long date = 0;
        public int callDuration = 0;
    }
```

When I run the program, I get the following error in the console

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'callType' property not found on 'object' ''CallLogInformation' (HashCode=24457251)'. null

Comment: Your CallLogInformation class has no properties, but only public fields (and of course the enum declaration). Data binding however only works with public properties. You should read the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) article on MSDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the callType to a property instead of a field

eg

```
public CallType callType { get; set;}
```

WPF look up for properties instead of fields, in your current implementation of `CallLogInformation` class `callType` is defined as field

you may perhaps need other properties to be binded to the UI so you may need to convert them all

example

```
public class CallLogInformation
{
    public enum CallType { INCOMING, OUTGOING, MISSED, UNKNOWN };
    public string contactNameOrPhoneNumber { get; set;}
    public ContactInformation contactInformation { get; set;}
    public CallType callType { get; set;}
    public long date { get; set;}
    public int callDuration { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Better change *all public* fields to properties.

Comment: So obvious now, thanks I completely forgot about that